# External display is showing and reporting wrong resolutions

Tags: xorg, graphics, display, resolution, x11

I'm running 11.04 in dual-boot on my macbook pro (2010). I've got an external monitor connected which I've configured through nvidia settings to be it's own X display.

When I open the nvidia settings app, it says my external display only supports 640x480. And even if I tweak the resolution options in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to use a specific (higher) resolution, it seems to be ignored.

My graphics card is an "NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M" and I have the latest drivers installed.

How do I get my external display to use its full capacity which is 1920x1080?

Another thing to note is that the external display is reporting to be 1680x1048 which is the size of my main laptop resolution.

How do I get my external display to use 1920x1080?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try out the UseEDID option to switch off reporting from the monitor.

See [here](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.09/README/appendix-b.html) for more information.